# How can I CORRECTLY formulate my "format" function?

Tags: formatting, common-lisp

I have a function:

```
(defun play (&rest args)
  (format nil "play ~A~{, ~A~}~%" (car args) (cdr args))))
```

And, as far as I can say, it should be used like this:

```
(play 1 2 3)
```

and, in this case return "play 1 2 3". Unfortunately, there is some error in this code, so my ***emacs*** editor returns this:

```
main.lisp:7:7:
  error: 
    don't know how to dump #<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-OUTPUT-STREAM {1004139673}> (default MAKE-LOAD-FORM method called).
    ==>
      #<SWANK/GRAY::SLIME-OUTPUT-STREAM {1004139673}>
    
  note: The first argument never returns a value.
  note: 
    deleting unreachable code
    ==>
      "play ~A~{, ~A~}~%"
```

Could you help me please writing this function?

Comment: It works for me; I can't reproduce the error with your code (after removing the extraneous parenth). Why are you using `\`#.*standard-output*` instead of `*standard-output*`, or better yet `t`?

Comment: Well, now I've changed it, so there's no errors anymore! Thanks all of you, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Error

In your code, you write:

```
(defun play (&rest args)
  (format #.*standard-output* "play ~A~{, ~A~}~%" (car args) (cdr args))))
```

Before the code is evaluated, it is first read: the source is turned into an abstract syntax tree, which is represented as lisp values. Upon encountering `#.*standard-output*`, the reader evaluates the next form, here `*standard-output*`: the actual stream bound to this variable when you *read* the form is stored in the structured-expression that is the source code of function `play`.

You can put arbitrary data in your code, notably strings, numbers, etc. Here your source code contains an instance of a stream. This could be a problem when you try to execute function `play`, because by the time you evaluate the function's body, the stream might be closed; it looks like you are trying to fix the stream to which you want the output to be written, but that's probably not a good way to do what you have in mind. If you edit your question to add more information about that, we can probably find better ways to solve your problem.

Storing the stream object is also a problem when you compile the code, which is probably the reason why you have this particular error here.

As noted in comments, this happens when you compile a file. If you are working with Slime, this may happen when the environment uses a temporary file to compile buffer regions.

So your error happen when using [`COMPILE-FILE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cmp_fi.htm); note in particular this paragraph in the spec:

> Programs to be compiled by the file compiler must only contain externalizable objects; for details on such objects, see Section 3.2.4 (Literal Objects in Compiled Files). For information on how to extend the set of externalizable objects, see the function make-load-form and Section 3.2.4.4 (Additional Constraints on Externalizable Objects).

The file compiler produces an object file (fasl extension). Some literal values like constant strings, etc. must be stored in the resulting file, in a way that they *similar objects* can be reconstructed when loading the file back ([§3.2.4 Literal Objects in Compiled Files](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bd.htm)). For most standard types, the Lisp compiler knows how to dump an object and load it back.

But here the compiler does not know how to dump a value of type `stream` during the compilation process. You could define methods for [`MAKE-LOAD-FORM`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ld_.htm) but some data are inherently hard to (de)serialize: how do we store threads or any other operating system resource?

### Format

Except from evaluating `*standard-output*` at read-time, the format works.

However, you decompose the list into its `car` and `cdr`, but:

1. you don't check if there are any element in the list; if `args` is NIL then the printed text is `"play NIL"`, which is ambiguous with a list of one element NIL; or maybe you only ever call the function with non-empty lists, and in that  case you probably should add `(check-type list cons)` to better catch programming errors. Alternatively, define `play` as follows:

   ```
   (defun play (arg &rest more-args)
     ...)
   ```

   Then, `ARG` is the car, and `MORE-ARGS` is the cdr, and the user cannot call the function with an empty list of args (the constraint is also more explicit in the function signature).
2. you decompose them to handle the addition of comma between elements, which is something that `format` can handle by itself already.

   ```
   (format t "~{~a~^, ~}" args)
   ```

   The `~^` caret operator exits the current iteration context in format if there are no remaining elements in the list being processed. So here, we only add a comma and a space when the are more elements in the list.
   Also, you may want to handle the empty list and print something else, like `not playing anything` in case the list is empty; in that case you use the following construct:

   ```
   "~:[  ...  ~;   ...  ~]"
   ```

   The bracket operator with a colon modifier is like an if, the part  before `~;` is for the NIL case, the part that follows `~;` is for the non-nil part; you would need to write something like this:

   ```
   (format t "~:[not playing anything~;play ~{~a~^, ~}~]" args args)
   ```

   Notice how `args` is supplied twice: first for the test, then it is consumed (only) in the true branch of the test. We can do a bit better by letting format rewind on its list of parameters, so that it can consume a single parameter `args` twice:

   ```
   (format t "~:[not playing anything~;~:*play ~{~a~^, ~}~]" args)
   ```

   The asterisk operator with colon modifier `~:*` changes which current parameter is being consumed by `format`, by going back one in the list of supplied argument.

You can read more about format here: [A Few FORMAT Recipes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html)

Comment: When I tested OP code with SBCL, CCL, and CLISP it worked in all three cases; under what circumstances might using `#.` here cause the error?

Comment: I can compile the function individually too (interactively), but when I put the function in a file and call compile-file, that's when I have the error message. This is probably when producing the fasl file

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out the problem here is the `#.*standard-output*`.  I think it might be worth explaining what this does and why it really can't work.

The process of compiling a a file consists of something like this:

1. read a form from the file;
2. turn that form into compiled code, which code may have in it various references to literal objects;
3. write that compiled code out to a fasl file.

What you are trying to do is, in (1), cause the reader (via `#.`) to evaluate an expression *at read time* and then wire it into the code as a literal value.  So in particular what ends up in the code is *not* a reference to a particular dynamic variable, `*standard-output*`, but *the stream to which that variable is bound at the moment the reader read the form*.

The compiler (2) doesn't really care about this: it's quite happy compiling code with any kind of literal in it, really.

But at (3), the system has to write this literal object out to a file, called 'externalizing' it.  And it has to do it in such a way that, later on, possibly in a different lisp image running on a different machine, a similar object can be constructed when the file is loaded.  What 'being similar' means has a fairly natural definition for something like a string, a cons or a symbol (and some other types as well).  The spec goes into some length to define what similarity means as well as what sorts of objects must be externalizable in subsections of [3.2.4](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bd.htm).

Apart from the types of objects which are required by the standard to be externalizable as literals, implementations are free to define others, and it is possible to define your own by defining methods on [`make-load-form`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_ld_.htm#make-load-form), although this is only portably possible for certain classes of objects.

However what is very clear is that it simply makes no real sense for some classes of objects to appear as literals in compiled files at all, because there's no useful definition of similarity which makes sense for them.

Streams are one of those classes.  To see why consider a bit of code like this

```
 (with-open-file (*standard-output*
                             "/my/directory/sdfghjk.out"
                             :if-exists :supersede)
              (compile-file "my-source-file.lisp"))
```

Now what should the file compiler do when it encounters a bit of source code whose textual form is

```
(defun foo ()
  #.*standard-output*)
```

for instance?  What the fasl dumper sees is a literal object which is a stream open to a particular file, in a particular directory on a particular machine.  What should it write to the fasl file such that, when the fasl file is later loaded, a similar stream can be created?  What does it even mean to construct a similar stream at all?  What should happen if the directory doesn't exist at the time the fasl file is loaded?

Well, the answer to this is that it doesn't, in general make any sense at all: there's no generally useful definition of similarity which applies to streams, because they are, by their nature, objects which make sense within a single running image.

Note again: what is ending up in the code is *not* a reference to a variable, which would be completely fine, it's a reference to *the object which was the value of that variable when the form was read* and it's this that causes the problem.

---

A final note: `#.` is a pretty nice thing, but like most nice things it has its downside.  In this case that downside is that *the reader can execute arbitrary code, at read time*, where 'arbitrary' means 'anything at all'.  This is perhaps reasonable when compiling code (if you trust the authors of that code), but in general the ability to execute arbitrary code when reading data has a name: code injection attack.  So if you are using `read` as a tool for reading data you don't completely trust, *turn this off* by binding `*read-eval*` to `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example works for me too (though it is contrived, see the comment).

However, here's an example using an external library, if/when you don't remember the format directives…

```
;; (ql:quickload "str")
(format t "play ~a" (str:join ", " (list 1 2 3)))
;; => play 1, 2, 3
```